# How to form dynamic link in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to form a link on the client end.

I think that need to be urlencoded but I am pretty confused with this. Is this right?

```
var link = document.createElement("a");

//addParams function just replaces the 0th and 1th occurrence with values 

a.link = url.addParams(valueO, value1); // url is /home/testpage.aspx?{0}={1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Shouldn't that be `link.href = url.addParams(valueO, value1);`?
- And both `value0` and `value1` should be sent (individually) through either `escape()` or [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) ([I believe the latter is recommended over `escape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_Functions)). You probably will want to do this in `addParams()` *before* you replace `{0}` and `{1}` in your URL string.

  You could also do something like `addParams(encodeURIComponent(value0), encodeURIComponent(value1))` but in my opinion, that's asking for trouble if you forget to encode some values in a call somewhere. It'd be better to move the encoding into the function itself.
- Here's an explanation of [what `escape(), encodeURI(), encodeURIComponent()` do and how they're different and when to use each](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do `link.href = escape("<your url>");` plus you need to add some innerHTML - `link.innerHTML = 'Click Here';`

...and then finally add it into the page at some point.

Comment: but what about encoding ? do we have to explicitly handle it ?

Comment: i agree w/ the above. modified the post.

Comment: AFAIK, `escape()` is not very safe since it only works with ASCII. Also, it's going to leave valid URI character in the query string untouched which might be a problem. It's best to encode each key-value pair in the query string separately using `encodeURIComponent()` where available.

Answer (score 0):

```
var link = document.createElement('a');

var href = document.createAttribute('href');

link.setAttribute(href,'http://www.example.com?'+paramKey+'='+paramValue);

link.innerText ="Go here";
```

Comment: Firefox and some other browsers uses `textContent` rather than `innerText`.